# snowflake show Roles does not show the user name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Show ROLES provide me the info about Roles and user to whom the roles are assigned to.
However instead of providing the username it gives the user number like below in assigned_to_users

show roles;

```
---------------------------------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
           created_on            |     name      | is_default | is_current | is_inherited | assigned_to_users | granted_to_roles | granted_roles |     owner     |         comment          |
---------------------------------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
 Fri, 05 Dec 2014 16:25:06 -0800 | ACCOUNTADMIN  | Y          | Y          | N            | 1                 | 0                | 2             |               |                          |
 Mon, 15 Dec 2014 17:58:33 -0800 | ANALYST       | N          | N          | N            | 0                 | 6                | 0             | SECURITYADMIN | Data analyst             |
 Fri, 05 Dec 2014 16:25:06 -0800 | PUBLIC        | N          | N          | Y            | 0                 | 0                | 0             |               |                          |
 Fri, 05 Dec 2014 16:25:06 -0800 | SECURITYADMIN | N          | N          | Y            | 0                 | 1                | 0             |               |                          |
 Fri, 05 Dec 2014 16:25:06 -0800 | SYSADMIN      | N          | N          | Y            | 5                 | 1                | 2             |               |                          |
---------------------------------+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

is there a way I can join the number to actual user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHOW USERS is show you the count of users it is assigned to:

`SHOW USERS;`

| created_on | name | is_default | is_current | is_inherited | assigned_to_users | granted_to_roles | granted_roles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-06 | USERADMIN | N | N | Y | 0 | 1 | 0 |

```
create user testo;

grant role useradmin to user testo;

SHOW USERS;
```

| created_on | name | is_default | is_current | is_inherited | assigned_to_users | granted_to_roles | granted_roles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-06 | USERADMIN | N | N | Y | 1 | 1 | 0 |

You might want the [SHOW GRANTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html) command, in the `show grants of role <role_name>;` form? But that will require multiple requests to see all GRANTS of ALL roles to all users.

OR on a per database level [information_schema.APPLICABLE_ROLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/applicable_roles.html):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.APPLICABLE_ROLES;
```

| GRANTEE | ROLE_NAME | ROLE_OWNER | IS_GRANTABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIMEON | ACCOUNTADMIN |  | NO |
| SIMEON | ORGADMIN |  | NO |
| SIMEON | PUBLIC |  | NO |
| ACCOUNTADMIN | SECURITYADMIN |  | NO |
| ACCOUNTADMIN | SYSADMIN |  | NO |
| SECURITYADMIN | USERADMIN |  | NO |

Answer (score 2):

[GRANTS_TO_ROLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_roles.html) View holds the privileges granted to roles.

[GRANTS_TO_USERS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_users.html) View holds the roles granted to the users.

You can join them as follows to get what you're looking for:

```
select u.grantee_name
    , u.role
    , r.privilege
    , r.granted_on
    , r.name
from snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_users u
join snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_roles r
on u.role = r.grantee_name
where u.grantee_name = '<user_name>'
order by 1,2,3,4,5;
```