# How to see list of users in a role snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We can see what roles are assigned to a user but how do I see the list of users in a role snowflake?

For example I have a role svn_dev_admin , I need to see all users under this role
Thanks,
Xi

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390456/snowflake-show-roles-does-not-show-the-user-name) answer your question?

Comment: no,   For example I have a role svn_dev_admin , I need to see all users under this role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should give you users list for the role specified and the role(s) under that.

```
-- since role_name used in the query twice, set it to a parameter
set role_name = 'svn_dev_admin';  

select GRANTEE_NAME
 from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS
where ROLE = $role_name
  and DELETED_ON is null
union 
select GRANTEE_NAME
  from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_USERS
 where ROLE IN (select NAME
                  from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES
                 where GRANTEE_NAME = $role_name)
   and DELETED_ON is null;
```

If you want to see the users got the access with a lower level role to the given role you can add the `ROLE` column to the query like the following, but it might create duplicate user names

```
select ROLE, GRANTEE_NAME
```

Answer (score 6):

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html will do what you want with:

```
SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE svn_dev_admin;
```

```
created_on  role    granted_to  grantee_name    granted_by
2018-11-12 15:18:07.580 -0800   SYSADMIN    ROLE    ACCOUNTADMIN    
2019-10-02 09:23:26.688 -0700   SYSADMIN    USER    XYZ ACCOUNTADMIN
2020-03-02 12:56:01.386 -0800   SYSADMIN    USER    ZYX ACCOUNTADMIN
```

Comment: just executed,  It doesn't have User information

Comment: Please look into Granted_To column, it says USER for the user objects granted to that ROLE

Answer (score 1):

You can just query the GRANTS_TO_USERS view

Comment: can you show an example

Comment: An example of how to query a view?

Comment: The result of querying GRANTS_TO_USERS view for a given role is the same as command SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE, so wouldn't work